# Any way to have custom movie artwork for movies purchased on iTunes spread to iPhone and iPad via iCloud?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipad, icloud, movie

I'm trying to have the custom artwork I apply to movies purchased on iTunes (applied through using 'Get Info' within iTunes on a Mac) spread to my iPhone or iPad. As it is, these changes appear to just be local to the machine, so I'm stuck with the default artwork for iOS devices as they appear in the TV app.

I'm looking for the artwork to sync via iCloud, but I'm not sure iCloud can do this.

Is there any way to have the custom artwork apply to iPhone or iPad via iCloud? If so, how?

Comment: When you say _applied through the 'Get Info' pane on a Mac_ do you mean you've done this within the Finder or that you're trying to change the artwork within iTunes?

Comment: I mean in iTunes - hitting 'Get Info' and pasting in a new image for the movie's cover.

Comment: Have you tried using iTunes to sync/copy across the movies to your iPhone/iPad (i.e. instead of relying on iCloud to do it)?

Comment: Haven't tried it. That may work but I'm trying to see if there's a way to have iCloud communicate these changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### iTunes movies

I have tested this with purchased movies from the iTunes Store.

It is **not possible** to change the artwork for purchased movies across devices using iCloud. The same is true for The movie title, summary, etc.

Changes to movie titles will be saved *locally*, even if you remove the download and download it at a later point in time. Other devices won't receive changed movie titles.

---

### Movies without DRM

Movies without DRM that you have added yourself to your iTunes Library can be synced locally to your devices. Changes made to the artwork of these movie files will be updated upon the next sync (via USB/Wi-Fi).